# I can’t seem to use std::optional with node-gyp

Tags: c++, compilation, c++17, c++20, node-gyp

Every time I try to compile my C++ code that uses `std::optional` with `node-gyp`, I get:

> error: no template named 'optional' in namespace 'std'

I assumed the problem was with the C++ standard (since I am obviously including the `<optional>` header in my code), and I’ve tried to set it to C++20 (or 17) with `cflags_cc`, `xcode_settings.CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD`, `xcode_settings.OTHER_CFLAGS`, etc.… Everything I could find, basically, yet I can’t get rid of that error.

Here’s my binding.gyp for reference:

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "clip_frame_cropper",
            "includes": ["auto.gypi"],
            "sources": ["./src/C++/clip_frame_cropper.cpp"],
            "include_dirs": ["/usr/local/include/opencv4"],
            "libraries": ["-lopencv_core", "-lopencv_imgproc", "-lopencv_videoio", "-lopencv_imgcodecs"],
            "cflags_cc": ["-std=c++20", "-Ofast"],
            "xcode_settings": {
                "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD": "c++20",
                "OTHER_CFLAGS": ["-std=c++20"],
                "OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS": ["-std=c++20"]
            }
        }
    ],
    "includes": ["auto-top.gypi"]
}
```

I am on the latest version of macOS… Also, the code compiles just fine outside of `node-gyp`, for what it’s worth.

By the way, literally any code that uses `std::optional` causes this issue, so it’s not my code that I am asking about, but rather `node-gyp`. Yes, even something like this:

```
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> test;
```

Comment: Maybe try adding the verbose (`-v`) flag to the compiler flags, see if it outputs what header file it's using for `<optional>`, and check if that header file has any preprocessor statements that could prevent `std:: optional` from being defined?

Comment: or try to see output of the preprocessor stage to see contents of the header directly. I dont think there is too much inside it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I was able to fix it thanks to the user who suggested passing the `-v` flag to get more info.

I realized the compiler was being executed with `-std=c++11` regardless of what flags I used, so I fixed it by adding the following field:

```
"OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS!": ["-std=c++11"]
```

The “!” is supposed to tell `node-gyp` to not use that flag. No idea why that’s necessary and I haven’t seen it anywhere else, but maybe it’ll help someone in the future.

Answer (score -2):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional says that `std::optional` is "Defined in header [<optional>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/optional)", so make sure to `#include <optional>`.

Comment: When I said I was including the header in my code, that is exactly what I meant. Not that I need it to compile it without node-gyp, anyways (maybe getting included by one of my other includes), but I still have it at the moment just to make sure I’m trying everything I can.

Comment: @RodrigoPelissier such misunderstanding can be avoided by including a [mcve] in the question

Comment: @RodrigoPelissier if this doesn't answer your question please post a [mre]

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Or by reading the entire question… Anyways, what else should I provide besides the binding.gyp? Any code that uses std::optional should do; there is nothing else unique or written by me here.

Comment: @RodrigoPelissier you think it would be obivous. Though obviously it isnt. If any code suffices why not include the 2 lines in the question?

Comment: @RodrigoPelissier what is suspicious is that the error does not complain about `<optional>` being found but lets that pass. I am geniuenly interested in seeing the code, its not mere pedantry

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Not obvious, but rather trivial and nonspecific, I guess… Either way, I’m not here to argue or anything; I appreciate any efforst to try and help.

Would something like this do for you?

#include <optional>

std::optional<int> test() {
    return std::nullopt;
}

Literally anything that calls std::optional in any way gives the same error, so it doesn’t really matter what the code itself does.

Comment: @RodrigoPelissier doesnt matter if it does for me. The question is: Does it do for you? Does the code reproduce the error ? If yes include it in the question

Comment: @RodrigoPelissier I mean, sorry, I don't want to sound annoyed. The thing is just that you want to put us in the position to know the issue with compiling your code. Not showing the code is not good. Showing the code is good. We cannot know what code you use to get the error unless you tell us

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It’s just that I was being serious when I said literally anything with std::optional in it causes the issue. It simply feels kinda weird to me to include some code that does nothing and isn’t exactly relevant to my problem, either; it could be replaced with anything. I also wish to keep it simple and keep any distractions to a minimum. I guess I could link the repo with the code, but again, I am not asking about my code here; I am simply asking about node-gyp. And, as stated in the question itself, the code compiles just fine if I do it myself.

Comment: "I am not here to argue.." arguing and refusing to show the code since 40 minutes....

Comment: @RodrigoPelissier details matter. I am almost certain I can write code that compiles with one compiler and produces exactly this error message with a different compiler and the fix would be to add a missing include.

Comment: @RodrigoPelissier we cannot know if the issue is caused by an implicit transient include or not if you do not show the code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I literally just showed you an example in a comment above with only a couple of lines. Said example, same as my code, includes the <optional> header, like I keep saying. I prefaced my entire question by mentioning the header is being included so nobody would waste time on that, yet here we are… I’ll say it again, the header IS being included and LITERALLY anything with std::optional in it causes this. I’ll even update my question to make that even clearer than it already is. I just feel like you keep focusing on the wrong thing… Thank you, but this is not helpful.